# String convert to variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React I have stored images in different variables like

```
import Small from '../images/small.png' 
import Medium from '../images/medium.png'
```

And I store these variables in a data.js file like

```
const Paper = [{ Head: "<strong>Heading Content</strong>sub-heading", content: ["Small","Medium"] },{ Head: "<strong>Heading Content 2</strong>sub-heading", content: ["Small","Medium"] }...];
```

Then print this datas in my page `Heading` are print okay but the the images not showing:

```
{Head}
{Paper.map((Paper,index) => (
  <div className='news-papper'>
    <img className='images' src={images[index]} alt='ans-img'/>
  </div>
))
}
```

how to print the image from JSON data in react, I am new in react.

Comment: What JSON data?

Comment: @evolutionxbox { Head: "<strong>Heading Content</strong>sub-heading", content: ["Small","Medium"] },...

Comment: Quick clarification: That's not JSON.

Comment: That's just a javascript array. JSON is the stringified representation of javascript objects.

Anyway in your html snippet i see you are getting the image url from `images[index]` and you are saying there is no image shown.  What is `images` and how you fill it?

Comment: Also, `["Small","Medium"]` doesn't store the images. They're only strings in an array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  i also store a image in these variables

Comment: If you want to refer to your imported images you should include them in the array like this `[Small, Medium]`.  Like @evolutionxbox says, those are just strings instead.

Comment: @doc then how we call images from objects

Comment: @evolutionxbox how we call  images from object in react

Comment: This last question is not super-clear to me.  Your `Small` and `Medium` variables, aren't nothing more then strings (your images paths).
For example you could render the Small image by doing `<img src={Small} />`.

So, you can put you image path in some array like `const images = [Small, Medium]`, then render your 2 image with `{images.map(url => <img src={url} />)}`.  Hope this way is more clear

Comment: Or in a complex situation like yours, something like, for example, `const people = [{name: 'A', imageUrl: Small}, {name: 'B', imageUrl: Medium}]`  and then  `{people.map(person => <img src={person.imageUrl} />)}`.  I'm using this example with `people` because i'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do with your array, and where the images should be for you in your Paper array.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have your images in your public folder. If you build your project the folder structure you see during development will no longer exist because everything is bundled and minimized. The only folder that will remain intact is your public folder. If you store your images there you can have a subfolder and access it like so

```
./<your_subfolder_name>/<your_image.extension>.
```

If you use a custom public URL for your app you can also use them like so

```
`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/<your_subfolder>/<your_image.extension>`
```

Doing this allows you to pass the path directly to your image src attribute.

However, the problem here is your structure. The images array does not exist as I can see and even if it existed your reference to the images is as strings.

You can try a structure like this:

```
let data = [
 {
   head: <strong>Content without quotation. It's JSX and it can be rendered as 
         it is</strong>,
   imagePath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/my_image.png`
 }
]
```